# How to assert multiline regex in python

Tags: python, regex

Why does this test fail?

```
import re
def test_Items():
    items = '''
    - item
    - item
    '''
    list_regex = re.compile(r"^- .*\n", re.MULTILINE)
    assert list_regex.match(items)
```

I'm having a hard time understanding the error message:

```
E       AssertionError: assert None
E        +  where None = <built-in method match of re.Pattern object at 0x7f8df4dbe240>('\
n    - item\n    - item\n    ')                                                          
E        +    where <built-in method match of re.Pattern object at 0x7f8df4dbe240> = re.co
mpile('^- .*\\n', re.MULTILINE).match
```

Comment: Use `re.search`, `re.match` only finds matches at the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the string `items` begins with a newline and several spaces, and ends with several spaces.  When using `'''`, the first character of the string starts immediately after the opening `'''`, and the last character of the string is immediately before the closing `'''`.

So `items` is:

```
'\n    - item\n    - item\n    '
```

You can fix it by doing:

```
    items = '''- item
- item
'''
```

Or you can do:

```
items = '- item\n- item\n'
```

Note that I also removed the leading spaces in the second line, as Baramar suggested.

Also note that `re.match` anchors the search at the start of the string.  If you want to match any of the lines in the string, use `re.search` instead.

Comment: I think he should get rid of the indentation on all the lines, not just the first line. He's using `re.MULTILINE` so that `^` will match any of the newlines.

Comment: @Barmar That's a good point, I removed the spaces from my examples.